# How to show dropdown when minLength is 0 ngInputTag?

Tags: angularjs-directive, typeahead, ng-tags-input

I am using ngTagInput library ref:  http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/ which I customized a little to meet my requirement.

Now I want dropdown be shown with fetched data as soon as input is focused.

```
 E.g.
            users = ["stack" ,"subj" ,"owner"];

            1. Now on focusing input ("Add User"), all three users should be fetched.
            2. After I input "s",then, only "stack" and "subj" should be shown.


           For that, I tried ng-focus= "newTagChange()" instead of ng-change="newTagChange()". 
           But it didn't work as expected. 

           I also tried with minLength="0" which failed as well.
```

Find current implementation at:`Plunker` http://plnkr.co/edit/shgh40H3Nc0eEeM4Lidd?p=preview

Please suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That feature is now available in the [master branch](https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput) of the project on GitHub. You might want to rebase your fork on top of it.

Here's how to enable that behavior:

```
<tags-input ng-model="tags">
    <auto-complete source="loadTags($query)" 
                   load-on-empty="true" 
                   load-on-focus="true">
    </auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```

Setting `loadOnEmpty` to true will make the directive call the load function when the input content becomes empty, and setting `loadOnFocus` to true will do the same when the input gains focus.